# Redirect to dynamic sitemap or generate it through yiic?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, sitemap

I want to render dynamic sitemap for yii site.
But i've failed to do it in url manager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(                
    'showScriptName'=>false, 
    'rules'=>array(                 
        'sitemap.xml/*'=>'/site/sitemapxml', 
        array('site/sitemapxml', 'pattern'=>'sitemap.xml', 'urlSuffix'=>''),
 ...
```

so i turned to `.htaccess` and i added a redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /app3/sitemap.xml http://tarex.ru/app3/index.php/?r=site/sitemapxml
```

Another option is to generate sitemap.xml as an file through [an extension in terms of a yiic command](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/670-yiic-sitemap-generation/page__view__findpost__p__3655). Would it be more time/recourse efficient?

Comment: For highly dynamic sites, a sitemap might not be a great idea. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14011057/2624391) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your rule was incorrect, use this instead:

```
'rules' => array(                 
    '/sitemap.xml' => '/site/sitemapxml', 
    ...
)
```

Now, regarding your question, it doesn't really matter that much, which way you will prefer, each of them has its own cons and pros.

### Controller action option

**Pros:**

- Easy to implement and sustain. It's just another action, you won't forget how sitemap is generated in your system.

**Cons:**

- Dynamic content, therefore, lower performance.

**Solution:**
use [COutputCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/caching.page) filter for caching. Add this filter to your SiteController:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'COutputCache + sitemap',
            'duration' => 24 * 60 * 60 // cache for 24 hours
        ),
    );
}
```

Don't forget to configure `cache` component in your configuration file. Use [CFileCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileCache) for that. Read the [corresponding section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) of The Definitive Guide to Yii if you're not familiar with this topic.

It's a pretty flexible solution, you can extend this example to make it reading caching duration from your configuration file if needed.

### yiic option

**Pros:**

- sitemap.xml is just a static file, served more efficiently by the web server

**Cons:**

- need to update it regularly and control this process
- need to use something else except the framework, this requires some monitoring as well

**Solution:**
use a cron job to generate `sitemap.xml`.

Although the final decision highly depends on particular details of the project, generally, I'd stick to the first approach.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Especially for the cashing part. Could you provide some more info on requests' cashing?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Caching is a vague topic. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: i mean some links to the examples of cashing, where to start from since i've not done it before.

Comment: I'd start with the official documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview, then I like how caching is explained on an example in this book http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Application-Development-Yii1-1-PHP5-ebook/dp/B0058HHETA.